# Associativity of symmetric difference

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have the definition $A+B=(A - B)\cup (B- A)$ for $A,B\in P(X)$, where $X$ is a set and $P(X)$ is the power set.

$+$ should be associative since $P(X)$ is a group, but I cannot prove that $(A+B)+C=A+(B+C)$.

I computed $(A+B)+C$ as follows
$$(A+B)+C=\{[(A - B)\cup (B- A)]+ C\}
\\=  \{ [(A - B)\cup (B- A)] -C \}\cup \{C- [ (A - B)\cup (B- A) ]   \} 
\\ =  \{ [(A\cap B^c)\cup (B\cap A^c)] -C \}\cup \{C- [ (A\cap B^c)\cup (B\cap A^c) ]   \} 
\\= \{ [(A\cap B^c)\cup (B\cap A^c)]\cap C^c \}\cup \{C \cap [ (A\cap B^c)\cup (B\cap A^c) ]^c   \}
\\=  \{ [(A\cap B^c)\cup (B\cap A^c)]\cap C^c \}\cup \{C \cap [ (A\cap B^c)^c\cap (B\cap A^c)^c ]   \}
\\=  \{ [(A\cap B^c)\cup (B\cap A^c)]\cap C^c \}\cup \{C \cap [ (A^c\cup B)\cap (B^c\cup A) ]   \}   $$

On the other hand $A+(B+C)$ is

$$ A+(B+C)= A + [ (B-C)\cup (C-B) ]
\\= \{  A-[ (B-C)\cup (C-B) ] \}\cup \{[ (B-C)\cup (C-B) ]-A  \} 
\\= \{  A\cap[ (B\cap C^c)\cup (C\cap B^c ) ]^c \}\cup \{[ (B\cap C^c)\cup (C\cap B^c) ]\cap A^c  \}
\\= \{  A\cap[ (B^c\cup C)\cap (C^c\cup B ) ] \}\cup \{[ (B\cap C^c)\cup (C\cap B^c) ]\cap A^c  \}$$

I tried to calculate further but I didn't get the same expression for both sides. Any ideas?

Comment: I refuse to look at any proof with reference to the complement @_@

Comment: You might show that $A+B+C$ is the set of all elements contained in an odd number of the summand sets

Comment: The power set $P(X)$ is isomorphic to the set of functions $X \to \{ 0, 1 \}$ by associating any subset of $X$ to its indicator function. Under this mapping, the symmetric difference become pointwise addition modulo $2$. Since this sort of pointwise addition is associative, so does symmetric differences among subsets of $X$.

Comment: For the "grind it out" method, rather than the slick method that @achille hui mentioned (see also [here](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=7483025)), see [these notes by Doug Rall at Furman University](http://math.furman.edu/~drall/mth320-2012/Ex11-22.pdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the notation change: union ($+$), intersection ($.$), complement ($'$), plus ($\oplus$), minus ($\ominus$), with the usual properties.

Thus:
$$
A \ominus B=AB'\\
A \oplus B = (A \ominus B) + (B \ominus A) =AB'+A'B\\
$$
and:
$$
(A \oplus B)\oplus C=(AB'+A'B) \oplus C\\
=(AB'+A'B)C'+(AB'+A'B)'C\\
=(AB'+A'B)C'+(AB')'(A'B)'C\\
=(AB'+A'B)C'+(A'+B)(A+B')C\\
=(AB'+A'B)C'+(A'A+A'B'+AB+BB')C\\
=AB'C'+A'BC'+A'AC+A'B'C+ABC+BB'C\\
=(AB'C'+A'BC'+A'B'C)+ABC\\
$$
The last expression is symmetric in $A,B,C$, hence the requested property is proven.